# Изменение элемента, который не принадлежит adapter-у

Tags: android, recyclerview, adapter

У меня есть `RecyclerView`, для него я написал `adapter`. И мне надо, чтобы когда `RecyclerView` пустой, на экране появлялась надпись "Список пуст". Как мне изменять родительское `view` из `adapter`, или как это сделать по другому?

Answer (score 4):

Обычно это делается примерно так:

1)Сначала рядом с `RecyclerView` в лейауте лепим `TextView`, примерно так:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recordRecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:id="@+id/emptyText"
    android:text="Список пуст"
    />
```

2)Далее в фрагменте/активити там где заполняем данными `RecyclerView` втыкаем примерно следующий вызов:

```
    int itemCount = adapter.getItemCount();
    if(itemCount > 0)
        emptyText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    else
        emptyText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Я так и делал, но проблема в том, что если вставить эту конструкцию в  `onStart`. То она сработает только при старте активити, а в то время когда данные изменяются, она никак не работает

Comment: @AntonioFrank ну дык это всего лишь означает, что недостаточно ее вставлять только в `onStart()` - попробуйте забить его в отдельный метод и дергать его например при `notifyDataSetChanged()` или рядом с ним... Никто не говорил, что будет просто :)

Answer (score 0):

1й вариант это использование LiveData. И каждый раз при удалении/добавлении элементов передавать в лайвдату список элементов. Ее же завязать на активность и при ее изменении проверять если кол-во элементов 0 то выводить надпись "Список пуст".

2й вариант создать интерфейс

```
interface OnItemsChangedListener {
    fun onItemsChanged(list: ArrayList<Any>)
}
```

передавать его в adapter

```
var callback: OnItemClickListener? = null
```

И каждый раз при удалении/добавлении элементов передавать элементы в интерфейс

```
holder.buttonRemove.setOnClickListener {
            if(callback != null) callback.onItemsChanged(items)
        }
```

там где мы объявляем adapter

```
val adapter = MyAdapter(items)
adapter.callback = object : OnItemClickListener {
        override fun onItemsChanged(list: ArrayList<Any>) {
            if(list.isEmpty) {
                //show empty text
            }
            else {
                //hide empty text
            }
        }
}
```

3й вариант (не рекомендую) передавать родительский контейнер в адаптер и там над ним проводить манипуляции